# get a column data into a text file one by one?

Tags: php

the csv data as the following:

```
  (first line)   price   url

  (second line)    $10   src="http://www.test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/"||

  (third line)    $20  src="http://www.test.com/2260/"||src="http://www.test.com/2261/"||

      ....   ........
```

now i want to put all the data from the url column into a text file. and shows the data one by one. namely:

```
http://www.test.com/1455/
http://www.test.com/image/1456/
http://www.test.com/2260/
http://www.test.com/2261/
....
```

now,i am stucked.

a, i don't know how to prevent outputting the first line.
b,i don't know how to get the url, and put them i a text file one by one.

first i using the following code to output the data to the screen.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $row++;

       echo $data[1] . "<br />\n";

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

the above code also output the first line (url). i don't want to output it. how should i do. 
thank you.

Comment: remove the echo statement if you don't want to echo the output.

Comment: i want to echo the content not the header. thank you

Comment: I think what you are saying is that you want to skip the first line of output, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! I have modified your code just slightly to do what you're trying to do. Essentially you need a second file handler for the output. You can open that as append mode so that write append to the end of the file. As for not echoing the header, you just make sure that row is greater than the first row. Hope it helps!

```
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE && ($handle2 = fopen("output.txt", 'a')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if($row > 1) {
                fwrite($handle2, "{$data[1]}\n");
            }
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        fclose($handle2);
    }
```

Comment: thank you, i put your code in and run it. showing Notice: Undefined offset: 1  and all the content are in the output.txt but not one line by one line

Comment: i only need [link](http://www.test.com/1455/) this part. there must be an extration and split to the line content src="test.com/1455/"||src="http://www.test.com/image/1456/…. i don't know how to do. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe sometimes there isn't a value in the 1st index of $data so you could do an isset($data[1]) to make sure that it's there before writing it out.

Comment: I see what you meant about the url. Try using some regex to extract it out of the value of $data[1]. Give it a try and if you have trouble with it let us know!

Comment: You could also try to use PHP's explode() function to break it up if regex doesn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

// Skips the first line of the CSV - outputting the second "column" of data.

```
$row = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if ($row > 0 ) {
          echo $data[1] . "<br />\n";
        }
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```